# Bazel rules for Qt6 on Linux: How to copy required libs?

Tags: linux, qt, bazel, bazel-rules, qt6

Currently, I am working on an experiment to support [Qt6](https://www.qt.io/product/qt6/technical-specifications) via [Bazel](https://bazel.build/). My code can be found [here](https://github.com/Vertexwahn/rules_qt6).

On Linux with Bazel and GCC9 installed you can test my Qt6 Bazel rules via:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/Vertexwahn/rules_qt6
cd rules_qt6
bazel run --config=gcc9 //:Qt6HelloWorld # run Qt6HelloWorld binary
```

When trying to run `Qt6HelloWorld` this error gets reported:

```
/home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_$USER/196a14423fc09522ef7bd657344d1cd0/execroot/Qt6Testbed/bazel- out/k8-fastbuild/bin/Qt6HelloWorld:
error while loading shared libraries: libQt6Network.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

There seem to be a `libQt6Network.so`, `libQt6Network.so.6` and `libQt6Network.so.6.1.0` in Qt6.1.0. If I copy those files to `bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin` (where the `Qt6HelloWorld` binary resides) I still get this error.

Any ideas on how to fix this error?
Any ideas on how I can extend my rules to copy over those required libs so Bazel is happy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a late reply, but I just came across your rules trying to do something very similar.

The main issue here seems to be that in your rules you reference `libQt*.so`, which are symlinks to the actual libraries. Bazel correctly creates a symlink to those in the runfiles directory (under `_solib_k8`) and puts the relative path from the main binary to the paths under `_solib_k8` into the binary's `RUNPATH`. However, the `DT_NEEDED` entries in the binary refer to files ending in `.so.6` (probably because that's the `SONAME` of the library). Those aren't found in any of the directories, giving you the error above. Here are some details:

```
$ readelf -d [...]/execroot/Qt6Testbed/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/Qt6HelloWorld
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libQt6Network.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libQt6Qml.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libQt6Core.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libQt6Gui.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libQt6Widgets.so.6]
[...]
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [$ORIGIN/_solib_k8/_U@qt_U6.1.0_Ulinux_Udesktop_Ugcc_U64_S_S_Cqt_Unetwork_Ulinux_Uimport___Ulib:$ORIGIN/_solib_k8/_U@qt_U6.1.0_Ulinux_Udesktop_Ugcc_U64_S_S_Cqt_Uqml_Ulinux_Uimport___Ulib:$ORIGIN/_solib_k8/_U@qt_U6.1.0_Ulinux_Udesktop_Ugcc_U64_S_S_Cqt_Ucore_Ulinux_Uimport___Ulib:$ORIGIN/_solib_k8/_U@qt_U6.1.0_Ulinux_Udesktop_Ugcc_U64_S_S_Cqt_Ugui_Ulinux_Uimport___Ulib:$ORIGIN/_solib_k8/_U@qt_U6.1.0_Ulinux_Udesktop_Ugcc_U64_S_S_Cqt_Uwidgets_Ulinux_Uimport___Uli]
[...]
```

Examining the first `.so` in the first directory on the `RUNPATH`, we get this:

```
readelf -d [...]/execroot/Qt6Testbed/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/_solib_k8/_U@qt_U6.1.0_Ulinux_Udesktop_Ugcc_U64_S_S_Cqt_Unetwork_Ulinux_Uimport___Ulib/libQt6Network.so

Dynamic section at offset 0x206960 contains 36 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
[...]
 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libQt6Network.so.6]
[...]
```

The obvious fix is to use `libQt*.so.6` for the `cc_import` targets, but then we have to skip the `interface_library` argument, since apparently that one must end in `.so`. However, I'm not sure what benefit adds `cc_import` over `cc_library` anyways, at least on Linux. So I would advise using `cc_library` and simply `glob` something like `libQt6Core.so*`.

Once that is fixed, we face the next issue: `libicui18n.so.56` is required by at least one of the `libQt*.so` libraries, but we didn't provide that yet. Turns out it's required by all of them, so we can simply expand our glob. The result could then look like this:

```
[
    cc_library(
        name = "qt_%s_linux_import" % name,
        hdrs = [],
        srcs = glob([
            "lib/lib%s.so*" % library_name,
            "lib/libicu*.so*",
        ]),
        target_compatible_with = ["@platforms//os:linux"],
    )
    for name, include_folder, library_name, _ in QT_LIBRARIES
]
```

The last remaining issue is about the Qt platform plugin not being found. This can be fixed by providing the entire `plugins` directory via `data` and set `QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH`. The plugins we can put into a `filegroup` in `qt_6.1.0_linux_desktop_gcc_64.BUILD`

```
filegroup(
    name = "plugin_files",
    srcs = glob(["plugins/**/*"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

And then in the `cc_binary` put this as `data`:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "Qt6HelloWorld",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    deps = [
        ":qt_core",
        ":qt_qml",
        ":qt_widgets",
    ],
    env = select({
        "@platforms//os:linux": {
            "QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH": "external/qt_6.1.0_linux_desktop_gcc_64/plugins",
        },
        "@platforms//os:windows": {
            # TODO
        },
    }),
    data = select({
        "@platforms//os:linux": ["@qt_6.1.0_linux_desktop_gcc_64//:plugin_files"],
        "@platforms//os:windows": [],
    }),
)
```

Since I have put all of that up locally now, I will create a PR for your GitHub repo.